# How to fix 'Access is denied' errors when trying to .quit() Chrome in Selenium WebDriver tests?

Tags: selenium2, webdriver

Anyone know how to fix intermittent 'Access is denied' errors when trying to .quit() Chrome in Selenium WebDriver tests? It's happening about 1 in 10 times.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blah.py", line 30, in blah_test
    self.browser.quit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.15.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.
py", line 62, in quit
    self.service.stop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.15.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py
", line 94, in stop
    os.kill(self.process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

The code is (I've simplified it here):

```
from selenium import webdriver
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
self.browser.quit()
```

I'm on Windows 7 using latest ChromeDriver.exe (version 17 I think it is) and latest Selenium (2.15) and Python 2.7.x.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into that, but if it is a bug in Selenium, the easiest workaround would be to surround it in a try/catch and retry a few times.  I would follow up by asking (or searching for existing answers) whether it is a known issue on the Selenium users forum.

Comment: Sam, is there an 'official' forum for Selenium you could link me to? Or at least whichever one is the most highly-trafficed / likely to get responses? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed this. Yes, the selenium user forum is hosted on google groups: http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is not related with Selenium itself, but with python on Windows 7 (since it falls on *os.kill* method). How to fix it I don't have idea but there are some similar issues found while using words: [access denied process python windows 7](https://www.google.com/?q=access%20denied%20process%20python%20windows%207) on searching engine.